# Error Request to prepare SELECT type on PHP 5.3

Tags: php

I am trying to make a preparation type Select but it does not work and I can not see where the error is.

Thank you for your help and your explanations :)

```html
try{
        $sql  = " SELECT * FROM `eq_base`";
        $sql .= " WHERE  `eq_base`.`DateAchat` >= $sel_date or `eq_base`.`DateAchat` = \"0000-00-00\"  ";
        if (!("$sel_type"==99999))        { $sql .= " AND `eq_base`.`Type` = :sel_type"; }
        if (!("$sel_etat"==99999))        { $sql .= " AND `eq_base`.`Etat` = sel_etat"; }
        if (!empty("$sel_modele"))      { $sql .= " AND `eq_base`.`Modele` LIKE %:sel_modele% "; }
        if (!empty("$sel_fournisseur")) { $sql .= " AND `eq_base`.`Fournisseur` LIKE %:sel_fournisseur% "; }
        $sql .= " ORDER by `eq_base`.`cle`";
        var_dump($sql);
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $req = $db->prepare($sql);
        $req->bindValue(':sel_date',$sel_date);
        $req->bindValue(':sel_type',$sel_type);
        $req->bindValue(':sel_etat',$sel_etat);
        $req->bindValue(':sel_modele',$sel_modele);
        $req->bindValue(':sel_fournisseur',$sel_fournisseur);
        $req->execute();
        $temp = $req->fetchAll();  
        //$updated = $req->rowCount();
    }catch (Exception $e) {
              error_log($e);
              throw new Exception("Une erreur s'est produite lors de la création de l'équipement informatique.");
    }
  }
```

Comment: The bind variable in `sel_etat` is missing the `:`, also as you dynamically include various components of the SQL, this includes which bind variables exist.  So you may be binding to variables which aren't in the statement.

Comment: In the second line where you build your query, you have a PHP variable `$sel_date` in your query without quotes around it, whereas it probably needs it there. Seems like you have a quoting problem?

Comment: My advice would be not to code a complex query all at once, but start simple, test, correct, and then slowly build it up from there. This will prevent you from arriving in a situation where you don't even understand what might be wrong with your own code.

Comment: You're using or in the query and after that there may be bunch of ands. Try to place that OR in parenthesis:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you had some syntax mistakes like double quoting the variables inside the if statement `if (!("$sel_type"==99999))` and forgeting to put `:` before `sel_etat`.

Secondly you are creating the query dynamicaly but you are binding all the variables regardless. You should make the same checks as when you build your query to make sure you only bind variables that exist in your query.

Something like this should work

```
try{
    $sql  = " SELECT * FROM `eq_base`";
    $sql .= " WHERE (`eq_base`.`DateAchat` >= ':sel_date' or `eq_base`.`DateAchat` = '0000-00-00') ";
    if (($sel_type!=99999))        { $sql .= " AND (`eq_base`.`Type` = ':sel_type')"; }
    if (($sel_etat!=99999))        { $sql .= " AND (`eq_base`.`Etat` = ':sel_etat')"; }
    if (!empty($sel_modele))      { $sql .= " AND (`eq_base`.`Modele` LIKE '%:sel_modele%')"; }
    if (!empty($sel_fournisseur)) { $sql .= " AND (`eq_base`.`Fournisseur` LIKE '%:sel_fournisseur%')"; }
    $sql .= " ORDER by `eq_base`.`cle`";
    var_dump($sql);
    $db = Database::getInstance();
    $req = $db->prepare($sql);
    $req->bindValue(':sel_date',$sel_date);
    if (($sel_type!=99999)){
        $req->bindValue(':sel_type',$sel_type);
    }
    if (($sel_etat!=99999)) {
        $req->bindValue(':sel_etat',$sel_etat);
    }
    if (!empty($sel_modele)){
        $req->bindValue(':sel_modele',$sel_modele);
    }
    if (!empty($sel_fournisseur)){
        $req->bindValue(':sel_fournisseur',$sel_fournisseur);
    }
    $req->execute();
    $temp = $req->fetchAll();  
    //$updated = $req->rowCount();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e);
    throw new Exception("Une erreur s'est produite lors de la création de l'équipement informatique.");
}
```

Comment: Check my updated answer, I added single quotes for the values in the query

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($sql);`?

Comment: var_dump($sql) = string(180) " SELECT * FROM eq_base WHERE ( eq_base.DateAchat >= :sel_date or eq_base.DateAchat = "0000-00-00") AND eq_base.Type = :sel_type AND eq_base.Etat = :sel_etat ORDER by eq_base.cle"

Comment: and var_dump($resultat) = is a empty array

Answer (score 0):

Yes Dimitris my code is below and my log error also

```html
 try{
        $sql  = " SELECT * FROM `eq_base`";
        $sql .= " (WHERE  `eq_base`.`DateAchat` >= :sel_date or `eq_base`.`DateAchat` = \"0000-00-00\")  ";
        if ($sel_type!==99999)        { $sql .= " AND `eq_base`.`Type` = :sel_type"; }
        if ($sel_etat!==99999)        { $sql .= " AND `eq_base`.`Etat` = :sel_etat"; }
        if (!(empty($sel_modele)))      { $sql .= " AND `eq_base`.`Modele` LIKE :sel_modele"; }
        if (!(empty($sel_fournisseur))) { $sql .= " AND `eq_base`.`Fournisseur` LIKE :sel_fournisseur"; }
        $sql .= " ORDER by `eq_base`.`cle`";
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $req = $db->prepare($sql);
         var_dump($req);
         $req->bindValue('sel_date', $sel_date);
         if($sel_type !==99999){
             $req->bindValue('sel_type',$sel_type);
         }
         if($sel_etat !==99999){
             $req->bindValue('sel_etat',$sel_etat);
         }
         if($sel_modele !==99999){
             $req->bindValue('sel_modele','%'.$sel_modele.'%');
         }
         if($sel_fournisseur !==99999){
             $req->bindValue('sel_fournisseur','%'.$sel_fournisseur.'%');
         }
         $req-execute();
         $resultat = $req->fetchAll();           
    }catch (Exception $e) {
              error_log($e);
              throw new Exception("Une erreur s'est produite lors de la création de l'équipement informatique.");
    }
  }
```

LOG ERROR IS : PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function execute()

Comment: `$req-execute();` should be `$req->execute();`

Comment: this time, the code loads me the table but I do not recover any data, with the unprepared request I manage to recover data